# Right to Left text in SVG in Chrome 47

Tags: google-chrome, svg, right-to-left, tspan

When using RTL characters in svg chrome seems to freakout. It does not respect the `x` or `y` positions in different ways. for `x` 0 does not seem to be the left of the parent. Also the `y` position seems to reverse the vertical order of the `tspans`.

Is this a known bug? Is there any good way to get good RTL support in chrome? I also notice the selection does not select in the correct direction for RTL.

I tested FF 42 and there are some `x` positioning problems but the vertical order of `tspans` is correct. Also the selection is in the correct RTL direction.

[jsfidle here](https://jsfiddle.net/STHayden/5ucvL6wf/)

```
<svg width="600" height="448" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><text  x="0" y="0" style="
    font-size: 64px;
    fill: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    text-align: left;
  ">
  <tspan x="0" y="83.375">است، یعنی جمله‌ای که </tspan>
  <tspan x="0" y="195.375">تمامی حروف الفبای زبان </tspan>
  <tspan x="0" y="307.375">انگلیسی را در خود دارد. </tspan><tspan class="glyphRow" x="0" y="419.375">از این جمله برای آزمایش</tspan>
  </text>
  </svg>
```

Comment: Shouldn't you at least provide a [`writing-mode`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#SettingInlineProgressionDirection) attribute?

Comment: @squeamishossifrage writing-mode shouldn't be necessary.